# OSX: ssh: Could not resolve hostname: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: macos, networking, ssh, dns, network-shares

There are two mac hosts in my **Wi-Fi** network (laptop and Desktop)
I'm trying to ssh laptop from Desktop - everything works fine
When I'm trying to ssh from laptop to Desktop doing this:

```
ssh macpro.local
```

I get this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

defining `usrename@macpro.local` or `root@macpro.local` makes no difference

But when I do this:

```
ssh 192.168.1.67
```

it works.

As I said I have no problem doing all this on my desktop.
Also when I do this (**on both computers**)

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -t
```

I get this:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed adding to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.67 macpro.local
```

For some reason ~/.ssh/config is not enough

Answer (score 4):

This message implies that you do not have sufficient filesystem permissions for the file containing your key. Use chmod 600  to set the rights correctly.

Comment: thank you, I've already found this out... Kinda fixed my ssh connection (deleting all the keys and generating them from scrach), BUT when doing `/usr/sbin/sshd -t` still get this: `Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key` interesting, that when I do `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t` I don't get any warnings... Could you explain why? And should I fix anything?

Comment: The system prevents you for starting sshd as standard user and using the systemwide hostkey. This is the reason why you did not get the message when using sudo. Sudo execute the followed command with admin rights. Then the sshd is able to use the hostkey from /etc.

Comment: I understand all this, but you didn't answer why and how to fix it. In fact I can ssh now as a standart user although I still have this messages...

Answer (score 4):

I met the similar issue, I can ping my `<hostname>` but when I ssh it, just report can't resolve.
I solved this problem by adding an empty line at the end of /etc/hosts!
By the way, it happened on macOS

Comment: I can't believe this just worked... I am astonished. Thank you! Even though I have no idea WHY it worked :D

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get "Could not load host key" is probably because those files contain private keys and are protected.  Try:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t
```

As to lookups for `macpro.local`not working, check sharing settings.  Below the "Computer Name" field, it should tell you the name that other computers can access your desktop with.  The "Edit" button lets you alter that.

Comment: well on the desktop `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t` gives the same result, but on laptop I get that nice msg:`@ WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! @` What should I do with it??? And as to sharing settings - all is correct and should work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had an issue with my `~/.ssh/config` file. I had to remove the host which was the host of my remote machine.
I just had to keep my `~/.ssh/config` as

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 22
```