# ssh: Could not resolve hostname - until restart

Tags: networking, macos, ssh

Just as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/879731/osx-ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-kno) I have two macs on my home wifi network.  Usually, I am able to use `ssh` to connect from one to the other, using either of:

```
ssh username@mac-name
ssh username@ip-address
```

Filling in the corresponding details for the actual computer name and ip address.  Periodically, however, I will get to a point where I can no longer do this and *both* of these fail. (this is where my situation diverges from the one described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/879731/osx-ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-kno)).

When I try `ssh username@mac-name` I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname mac-name: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

And when I try `ssh username@ip-address` I get:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

The situation is strange because:

- I am still able to connect to the other mac via screen sharing
- I am still able to connect to other networks via ssh
- If I restart my computer (the one I am trying to connect *from*) then the situation is resolved.

Based on the answers to [Strange NS behavior on OS X — can't connect to SSH server](https://superuser.com/questions/326848/strange-ns-behavior-on-os-x-cant-connect-to-ssh-server) I have tried:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

But neither of these resolved the issue.

What else can I try, short of needing to restart my computer each time this arises?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197637/cant-use-machine-name-to-login-using-ssh-anymore-on-yosemite-how-to-fix

I switched to using

```
ssh username@mac-name.local
```

and it seemed to clear things up.  Using

```
ssh username@ip-address.local
```

didn't work, but this seems less essential.